# Ошибки в вёрстке

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, разметка

Коллеги, всем привет)
Я - начинающий веб-разраб, изучаю вёрстку. Сверстал макет, и хотел попросить, если кому не трудно, взглянуть на мою работу и указать на ошибки. Буду Вам очень благодарен, друзья.
Вот ссылка на вёрстку - https://cleaning-company-001.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: Пробелы вокруг = уберите в тегах. Не закрывайте теги как в xhtml, времена уже не те. Коменты конца блоков не нужны. Коменты вообще не нужны там ни в html ни в css, и так всё очевидно. Классы и файлы называть нужно через кебаб-кейс, а не кэмел-кейс.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

[image: 1]

Сайт весом в 56MB даже по нынешним меркам это перебор.

```
border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
```

Свойство без префикса должно быть всегда ниже. Желательно используйте препроцессор [LESS](https://lesscss.org/)/[SCSS](https://sass-scss.ru/guide/) и [Autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer), чтоб не заниматься этим вручную.

```
.reviewsBlock .reviews .controls .buttons button
```

Старайтесь избегать цепочек селекторов и всему присваивать класс. В идеале, все селекторы должны быть вида `.my-class-name {}`.

```
<section class = "ourServices">
```

Куча лишних пробелов, используйте автоформат кода в вашей IDE, она сама лишнее уберёт.

[image: 5]

Не предусмотрен скролл элементов меню, при их переполнении.

[image: 6]

Не предусмотрено поведение сайта на больших мониторах.

[image: 7]

Не отцентрован тект.

И это только при беглом изучении. Так что удачи вам в изучении и учтите, что stackoverflow это база знаний, а не ресурс с бесплатными менторами.

Comment: Большое спасибо, очень ценные коментарии!)

Comment: Тогда, если можно, встречный вопрос: Вы сказали, что сайт в 56мб - это много. Как этого избежать? Просто это же вес контента - шрифтов, картинок и т.д.

Comment: @Константин оптимизация изображений, у Вас эта [иконка](https://cleaning-company-001.000webhostapp.com/pics/icons/common/blueArrowLeft.png) весит 2.2 мегабайта, например

Comment: Для оптимизации изображений можете использовать сервис https://tinyjpg.com/